# Google Forms - "go to section" conflict

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

Is there a way to have form "go to section" one after the other in case of conflict?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Let's say we have two questions with multiple-choice "go to section" set up, as you see above.
The thing is that Forms will base the logic only upon the last multiple-choice. This means that if I select anything in the 2nd question, it will ignore the answer to the first question.
While I do understand why this is programmed that way, I was wondering if there's a way to make them both work?
One idea was to send me to the sections one after the other. This would mean that "after section 1" should be dynamically updated from "submit" to "go to section 2". It cannot be always "go to section 2" as I don't always need to go to that section :)
One section after the other is just one idea. I'm sure there're other creative ways to solve this.
Any ideas?
Details

Comment: I wanted something similar, go to next section if any of the questions ask you to, and submit if they all say submit, not just based on the last question... this was a much better option if possible than the alternative rout I attempted of combining the questions (does not work if you wish to determine whether or not you want to go to section 2 then 3 or 2 then skip 3 by this question)

Answer (score 2):

**If both `question1` and `question2` are located in the same section, you cannot avoid conflicts by specifying different behavior after for responding those questions**

If the answer to the first question triggers "Go to section 2" and the answer to the second question triggers "Go to section 3" - how is the form supposed to know which request has priority.

**You need to restructure your logic**

- The easiest thing to do would be to split up `question1` and `question2` into separate sections
- For example: section 1 shall contian only `question1`, after answering which the user is redirected. After filling out the section to which the user has been redirected - implement a redirection the a new section, where question 2 is implemented.

Comment: Yes, the solution of duplicating sections is always possible but I wanted to avoid it.

Comment: I wouldn't know how.